# How to dynamically enable or disable the textbox by using jQuery in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

I have a ASP.NET MVC project with a large list of input textboxes which I want the user to control them independently. Here is the [**link**](http://www.popevent.co.uk/test/)  how it looks like now.

Here are some things I want to have:

1. Each enable/disable link only controls each row.
2. The number of rows is not fixed and it will be generated dynamically. It can be 10 or 20 rows.

**What is a generic way to do this?**

Here is my code sample:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    // first set
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".controller").toggle(

    function() {
        $('#target1').removeAttr("readonly");
        $('.controller').empty().append("Disable");
    },

    function() {
        $('#target1').attr("readonly", "readonly");
        $('.controller').empty().append("Enable");
    });
    });

</script>

<ul>
    <li>text field:
        <input type="text" readonly="readonly" id="target1" value="Change me" />
        <a href="#" class="controller">Enable</a><br />
    </li>
    <li>text field:
        <input type="text" readonly="readonly" id="target2" value="Change me" />
        <a href="#" class="controller">Enable</a><br />
    </li>
    <li>text field:
        <input type="text" readonly="readonly" id="target3" value="Change me" />
        <a href="#" class="controller">Enable</a><br />
    </li>
    <li>text field:
        <input type="text" readonly="readonly" id="target4" value="Change me" />
        <a href="#" class="controller">Enable</a><br />
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".controller").toggle(
        function() {
            $(this).prev("input[type='text']").removeAttr("readonly");
            $(this).text("Disable");
        },
        function() {
            $(this).prev("input[type='text']").attr("readonly", true);
            $(this).text("Enable");
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi rahul, thanks. What's the difference between .prev("input[type='text']") and .prev()?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('li .controller').click(function() {
    $(this).prev().removeAttr('readonly');
});
```

Or as following your example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".controller").toggle(
        function() {
            $(this).text("Disable").prev().removeAttr("readonly");
        },
        function() {
            $(this).text("Enable").prev().attr("readonly", "readonly");
        }
    );
});
```